# Moving the GeoServer data folder on Windows

Tags: geoserver

I get a 404 error after moving the the data folder when connecting to GeoServer server on Tomcat. How can I fix this?

I am running GeoServer 2.16 served by Tomcat 9 on Windows Server 2019 in a production environment.

I want to move the GeoServer data folder to a separate drive away from the Geoserver installation files. I have found various instructions for this and have done the following:

Copied the data folder to it's new location.
Uncommented the section in the web.xml file and added the file path to the data folder.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR</param-name>
    <param-value>D:\Geoserver_data\data</param-value>
</context-param>
```

(I have read somewhere that I should use double backslash or forward slash in the file paths because of Java syntax, all of which I have tried.)

I've then restarted Tomcat.
The result is a 404 error when connecting to Geoserver in a browser.

I have also given the Local Service account Read execute/Write/Modiy etc. permissions to the new data folder.

Where have I gone wrong for this to happen?

Comment: check that the user running tomcat (local service?) has permission to write to that directory

Comment: I had done this but neglected to include it in the original post.  The post is now updated.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 1):

under Windows Server 2016 I moved the data_dir to another drive just setting the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR environment variable and it works.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I understand this is required for standard Geoserver, but under my Tomcat installation, GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR doesn't exist.